# Selenium, setting a data input using Java

Tags: javascript, java, angular, selenium, e2e-testing

**The test goal**

I have an angular application with a form that I want to test. 
The form consists of two date input fields. I am trying to run an e2e test to test the form.

**Test 1**

My initial way of doing this was to straight forward, set the value the same way is done with text fields:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector)).sendKeys("2018-11-02");
```

Sadly the date is not copied over correctly.

[image]

Please note that I have tried to use other formats and that led nowhere.

**Test 2**

I have tried to use Javascript to update the fields.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('" + selector + "').value='" + value + "'");
```

I had more success with this, however angular digest does not seem to detect the changes and does not update reactive form.

I have tried to trigger the angular detection using Javascript but that did not work since we are running the test against a test environment that has a complied version of angular.

I tried to click on the parent component and run:

```
ng.probe(getAllAngularRootElements()[0]).injector.get(ng.coreTokens.ApplicationRef).tick()
```

I have also retrieved  the parent component on the input using document.querySelector and also using $1 and passed it to the ng.probe and that also led nowhere.

**Other solutions:**

I have checked online and have tried different solutions like:

- Clearing the field before running sendKeys function.
- Using Javascript to remove the readonly attribute

  document.querySelector('" + selector + "').removeAttribute('readonly',0))
- Using different date formats.
- Clicking on the input after updating its value.

Can anyone help solving this issue? I have checked several github threads and it seems that several people are having the same issue.

**Software versions:**

- selenium-java 3.13.0
- Chrome version: Version 71.0.3578.98
- Angular 6

**Please note:**
Protractor cannot be used because Java is already being used for testing purposes.

Comment: add html snip to question

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: WHY DON'T YOU JUST ENTER DIFFRENT DATE FORMAT: `webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector)).sendKeys("11-02-2018");`

Comment: OR if it doesn't work then, 11022018

Comment: @kushal.8 The format MMDDYYYY did the trick. Make your comment into an answer if you want to be awarded for your answer.

Comment: `11-02-2018` didnt work?

Comment: @kushal DD-MM-YYYY did not work. However, MMDDYYYY did work.

Comment: I actually meant MM-DD-YYYY?